# session cookies - users being logged out on first visit

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a users only section in my website, but on their first visit to the website (after having quit the browser or being on a new computer or not being logged in for a while), it will take them to the logged in home page fine, but when they try to navigate to a second logged in page from that home, they are automatically logged out. When they log in a second time, the effect is gone and everything works okay.

I have `session_start();` at the top of every page.

This is how I generate a session when a user logs in:

```
session_regenerate_id(true); // destroying the old session id and creating a new one
$_SESSION['id'] =  $login;
setcookie("id", $login, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
```

I have the sessions regenerate for security, but maybe I am doing it wrong and it's causing a problem?

**Logged In check:**

```
public function logged_in () {
    return(isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;
}

public function logged_out_protect() {
    if ($this->logged_in() === false) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Where is $login coming from?

Comment: It's the user ID, pulled from the database once the username and password check has passed.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the $login where you're trying to use it to set the session ID to make sure that variable is being populated correctly?

Comment: Could you also give us a better idea of how exactly the users are being "automatically logged out"?  The problem could just as easily be with the logic your code is using to boot the user.

Comment: $login is returning the correct value. See edits for "automatic logout".

Comment: It doesn't happen locally - only on the live server.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the session_regenerate_id to see if the problem persists?  Without seeing more of your code, I'd probably start commenting out things like that one at a time and check to ensure that values are being stored as intended.

Comment: @Mike After poking around, the only difference I noticed is that on the first login, there are two cookies, one for www.example.com, and one for example.com. Upon second login, there is only one cookie, for www.example.com, which is when everything starts working fine. Any ideas?